# Ruby: Not able to understand why class method is accessible in child class

Tags: ruby, inheritance, jruby

As per Ruby method lookup law whenever we invoke any method on an object then ruby finds the method using formula `object.class.ancestors`. If this is true then I should not be able to access parent method defined in parent class using `Child` class constant as `Child.parent` because the ancestors of `Child` class are `[Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`. But I can access it. Can anyone tell me why is so?

```
class Parent
  def self.parent
    puts "i am parent"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
end

Child.parent # i am parent
```

[image]

my jruby version is jruby 1.7.16 (1.9.3p392) 2014-09-25 575b395 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_20-b26 +jit [Windows 8.1-amd64]

Comment: You are using an **old** version of **j**ruby... I'm not familiar with the quirks of this old version. The answers below are correct for any modern ruby version, including modern jruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is not entirely correct. `object.class.ancestors` does not give you the full list of classes/modules where methods will be searched for. Here is a counter example:

```
foo = Object.new

def foo.bar
  puts "I'm inside the singleton class"
end

foo.class.ancestors # => [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
foo.bar # "I'm inside the singleton class"
```

Instead you have to start with the singleton class of the object:

```
foo.singleton_class.ancestors # => [#<Class:#<Object:0x007fa92c33c610>>, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
foo.singleton_class.instance_methods.include?(:bar) # => true
```

---

Knowing that when invoking `object.method_name`, `#method_name` is searched for somewhere in

```
object.singleton_class.ancestors
```

and that Ruby classes are regular objects, it only stands that with `Child.parent`, `#parent` will be looked for somewhere in

```
Child.singleton_class.ancestors
```

---

The magic is that class methods in Ruby aren't special in any way. They are just defined in the singleton class of the class. In your example:

```
Child.singleton_class.ancestors # => [#<Class:Child>, #<Class:Parent>, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

As you can see, the `Child`'s singleton class ancestors chain includes the `Parent`'s singleton class. That is why when you invoke `Child.parent` you actually call `Parent.parent`.

Comment: Child.singleton_class.ancestors giving me [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject] result and not the one which you have mentioned

Comment: @user2274074, that is not possible. Open a new irb, copy the code in the question and then execute `Child.singleton_class.ancestors`.

Comment: @user2274074, `[Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]` is the result of running `Child.class.ancestors`, not `Child.singleton_class.ancestors`.

Comment: i have edited my question and attached image after executing Child.singleton_class.ancestors and the result is still [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Comment: FYI , my jruby version is jruby 1.7.16 (1.9.3p392) 2014-09-25 575b395 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_20-b26 +jit [Windows 8.1-amd64]

Comment: @user2274074, ahaa **j**ruby.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157057/discussion-between-user2274074-and-ndn).

Answer (score 1):

> the parents of `Child` class are `[Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

No, they're not:

```
Child.ancestors
 #=> [Child, Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

You can access `Child.parent` because `Child` inherits from `Parent`.

In order to gain a *full* picture of what methods are available to instances of a class, however, you need to look at the `singleton_class`:

```
Child.singleton_class.ancestors
  #=> [#<Class:Child>, #<Class:Parent>, #<Class:Object>,
       #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object,
       Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Comment: I guess then lookup formula in the case of class is Class.ancestors and in the case of object is object.class.ancestors  ???

Comment: Did you enter: `Child.class.ancestors`? (It would have been helpful if you'd included this information in the original question.) `Child` *is* the class in question, so you did not need to use `Child.class`.

Comment: The "lookup formula", as you call it, is very simple. `klass.ancestors`. In this case, you needed `klass == Child`, not `klass == Class`.

Comment: if the lookup formulla is klass.ancestors then why i am able to access method defined in class 'Module' using Child class. for example class Module; def m;end; end;  Child.m ##is able to access method m here even if the Module is not the ancestor of the child class

Comment: @user2274074, the lookup "formula" for classes and objects is the same. Classes are objects. It's just that the formula isn't `anything.class.ancestors` but `anything.singleton_class.ancestors`.